# Number format in Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, number-formatting, openxml-sdk

I have some fields in an Word document with instructional text, for example like this one:

> { MERGEFIELD  MyField1 \# "000" }

I'm reading those fields using OpenXML SDK, as shown [here](http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/retrieving-fields-in-open-xml-wordprocessingml-documents/), and replacing them with some data.
I'm applying the number format that is specified in the field to my data, like this:

```cs
string fieldFormat = "000";
int data = 1234;
string fieldValue = data.ToString(fieldFormat);
```

In most cases this works great, but now I got a document that has "xxx" as a number format and when using the above I get "xxx" for `fieldValue`.

```cs
string fieldFormat = "xxx";
int data = 1234;
string fieldValue = data.ToString(fieldFormat); // Problem!
```

I saw that .NET doesn't support this in [Custom numeric format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings), but Word supports this in a way that it removes any digits that come after the "x" symbols place.
So for the above, it should result in "234". How can I do that in C#?

**EDIT, added some additional examples:**

```cs
int number = 1158;

string format1 = "x";
string format2 = "xx";
string format3 = "x#";
string format4 = "x,###";
string format5 = "x,xxx";
string format6 = "x##.00";
string format7 = "xxxxxxx.00";

Console.WriteLine("(number + format1) should result to: 8");
Console.WriteLine("(number + format2) should result to: 58");
Console.WriteLine("(number + format3) should result to: 58");
Console.WriteLine("(number + format4) should result to: 1,158");
Console.WriteLine("(number + format5) should result to: 1,158");
Console.WriteLine("(number + format6) should result to: 158.00");
Console.WriteLine("(number + format7) should result to: 1158.00");
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Be sure to include at least 7 inputs **and the expected results for those 7 inputs**.

Comment: Are you using any c# code in your process?

Comment: @mjwills I've added some additional examples.

Comment: @PeterSmith yes, I'm using the OpenXML SDK code that I linked to retrieve the field's format (the `fieldFormat` variable) and I have the `data` variable coming from a database. I need to combine those two and get the same value that MS Word gets.

Comment: I'm not aware of any C# formats that will do the masking you need but replacing `x` with either `#` or `0` would be a start. You could also write your own masking functions.

Comment: @PeterSmith yes that is what I'm asking, I don't know how to do the masking that you mentioned. Can you help me with that?